# Simple jQuery selector does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have no Idea why this selector does not work.

The HTML element is simply:

```
    <div id="myDiv">Original Text</div>
```

and the script I am using is simple:

```
    <script language="javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myDiv").innerHTML = "Replaced Text";
    });
```

for some reason this does not work, while two other options does work:

**Option 1:**

```
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerText = "This will work!"
```

**Option 2:**

```
    $("#myDiv").get(0).innerHTML = "This will work as well!"
```

Every tutorial I was reading is saying that the selector will simply work if I use $(#id) as I did.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("#myDiv")` is jQuery object, you can't set its `innerHTML` property because it doesn't have one.

Use the jQuery method [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
$("#myDiv").html("Replaced Text");
```

Option 1 works because it's just plain JS - you select the element and set its property. Option two works because you get the DOM element from the jquery object and set its property - also valid.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery objects use the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method, not `innerHTML`:

```
$("#myDiv").html("Replaced Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myDiv").html("Replaced Text");
    });
```